# Best way to handle articles with Django

Tags: django, django-models, article

I'm looking for the best possible way to manage articles in Django.

My idea was to load the articles as static files (there's no upload from users, so no form necessary, I guess), then create the model, but which field type to use here ? Textfield or FilePathField (in the static ?) or something else ? Then create the view and render it.

The articles will be showned as cards with a summary on the index page, and each card will point to the full article page.

If someone would point me in the right direction, I would appreciate. I'm checking the docs since yesterday, I might have missed the relevant part.

Comment: I believe, create a Article model having all the fields necessary instead of keep each article as a file, might be good idea, makes searching ( tags, author, content) more easier. like in django's offical doc, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/overview/#design-your-model

Comment: That was my first idea. Just was wondering if there was no better way. Thanks for your input